# Frida. Pass different agrument type in class method. Error "argument types do not match any of"

Tags: javascript, java, android, frida

I use frida to hook class. In my case HmacBuilder.
It has method hmacSha256Hex()

Here what method wants..

```
hmacSha256Hex('java.lang.String', 'java.lang.String', 'java.lang.String', 'okhttp3.RequestBody', 'java.lang.String')
```

If i call it and just pass strings for all of them.. like

```
instance.hmacSha256Hex("none","none","none","none","none"))
```

frida gives error

```
argument types do not match any of:\n\t.overload('java.lang.String', 'java.lang.String', 'java.lang.String', 'okhttp3.RequestBody', 'java.lang.String')"
```

Please advise, how should i call this method properly?(Preferably passing string as okhttp3.RequestBody?

My full inject_code.js

```
   console.log("Script loaded successfully ");
Java.perform(function x() {

    //Find an instance of the class and call function.
    Java.choose("com.testapp.HmacBuilder", {
        onMatch: function (instance) {
            console.log("Found instance: " + instance);
           console.log("Result of HMAC func: " + instance.hmacSha256Hex("none","none","none","none","none"));
           
        },
        onComplete: function () { }
    });
});


    console.log("Script finished ");
```

Comment: Robert, thanks a lot for pointing that out. Yes, i was afraid that recreating a class ok3hhtp.requestbody was the only option. Can you advise, how to create it via Frida, but with 2 string inputs?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "2 strings input". You can always concat two strings to one, e.g. using the [concat(String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#concat-java.lang.String-) method. Or try `+` operator, not sure if it works in frida JavaScript code for Android String arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there isn't an overloaded method that takes 4 String arguments you have to create and pass a RequestBody as fourth parameter, that is the way programming works. Why don't you try to create a RequestBody using [RequestBody.create(MediaType contentType, String content)](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/RequestBody.html)? For the MediaType [MediaType.get(String)](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/MediaType.html#get-java.lang.String-) should be the correct method.

Translated to code it should be code like this (untested) code:

```
let requestBodyText = "my text"; // <- define the request body text here

let requestBodyClass = Java.use("okhttp3.RequestBody");
let mediaTypeClass = Java.use("okhttp3.MediaType");
let mediaType = mediaTypeClass.get("text/plain");
let requestBody = requestBodyClass.create(mediaType, requestBodyText);

instance.hmacSha256Hex("none","none","none",requestBody,"none"))
```